# Рандомный вывод текста в TextView из готовой SQL

Tags: java, android, sql, kotlin

У меня есть заполненая SQL таблица, находиться в проекте, в папке `assets` (app/src/main/assets). Как мне рандомно выводить по `id` текст из таблицы в `TextView`, по нажатию кнопки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо:

1. Подключиться к БД.
2. Выполнить запрос на получение одного случайно элемента так: `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;`
3. Назначить полученное в п2 в TextView в качестве текста.